# How to write to a file using rapture-io

Tags: scala, rapture.io

I am trying to write to a file using rapture-io.

I would expect this to at least compile (sorry for importing the world, trying to get it to work):

```
import rapture.uri._
import rapture.io._
import rapture.fs._
import rapture.core._
import platform.posix
import rapture.codec._
import encodings.system
import modes.throwExceptions

val file = uri"file:///testFile.txt"
file > "hello world"
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

```
Cannot write Data data to String resources. Note that if you are working with Char data, you will require an implicit character encoding, e.g. import encodings.system or import encodings.`UTF-8`.
[error]       file > "hello world"
[error]            ^
```

Comment: Just a wild guess - would it work if you reverse the order, i.e. write `"hello world" > file`?

Comment: @vladimir Matveev That does not appear to work.